# How would one limit how many threads are used or created by Spark? (Databricks)

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j

Currently I'm using spark to write data into neo4j which when starting a write creates 200 threads writing into neo4j simultaneously. Is there a way to limit how many threads are created and used simultaneously or is the only way to decrease the cluster and instance size?
I know this kind of goes against what Spark is meant to do but would love to get any feedback.

I have tried
`spark.conf.set("spark.executor.cores", 4)`

with no Luck.

```
edges.write.format("org.neo4j.spark.DataSource")\
.option("url", "neo4j://url:7687") \
.mode("overwrite")\
.option("relationship", "connected")\
.option("batch.size",1000)\
.option("relationship.save.strategy", "keys")\
.option("relationship.source.node.keys", "id:id")\
.option("relationship.target.node.keys", "id:id")\
.option("relationship.source.labels", "node")\
.option("relationship.target.labels", "node")\
.save()
```

Comment: `spark.executor.cores` defines the number of threads per executor. So, if you set it to "1", you will reduce the number of writers to 1 per executor. This change is equivalent to reducing the cluster size, though, so it doesn't make much sense in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to repartition your dataframe before the write:

```
edges.repartition(parallelism)
...
.option("url", "neo4j://url:7687") \
.mode("overwrite")\
...
```

Where `parallelism` is the number of tasks that will be writing concurrently.

Comment: Repartition has worked for me I now only see the specified amount of connections created to neo4j. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The common solution is to [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.coalesce.html) (which is similar to `repartition` but much more efficient as it does not require a shuffle). Something like:

```
edges.coalesce(4).write...
```

One problem with this solution is that it assumes that `edges/4` fits in the memory of the executor. If it does, that works great; if not, I don't think there is a way to limit the number of writers except by reducing the cluster.